# Загрузка нескольких фото одновременно

Tags: изображения, javascript

Хочу сделать мульзагрузку для доски объявлений. Существующая загрузка добавляет фото по одному. Создает папку под номером на сервере, записывает в эту папку оригинал фото и уменьшеную копию. Таких папок столько сколько фото.

Проблема: Мультизагрузка осуществляется посредством js скрипта, но средства обработки (ресайза) фото в js примитивные, работают корректно не во всех браузерах и качество уменьшенных изображений оставляет желать лучшего. То есть если ресайзить фотки, то получится несколько кусков непонятно чего, а если загружать фотки в истинном размере, то у нас место на сайте через месяц закончится.

Как решить и сделать мультизагрузку?

В чем секрет вот этого? http://slando.ua/post-new-ad/

Comment: Удалять оригинальные фото с хостинга.

Comment: В чем секрет вот этого? http://slando.ua/post-new-ad/

Comment: @Greg8888 ни в чем, стоит мультизагрузка, обработка всех фотографий происходит на сервере (вдруг вы залили картинку 5000х4000, поверьте, их заливают очень часто). Обработка заключается в том, что фотография уменьшается, ужимается (возможно и превью создаются), оригинал удаляется за ненадобностью.

Comment: Похожие варианты скриптов есть такого? Кто-то встречал?

Comment: @Greg8888 берете любой плагин, который поддерживает мультизагрузку (например [jQuery-File-Upload][1]), дальше на сервере принимаете файлы, обрабатываете их, например [ImageMagick][2]


  [1]: http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
  [2]: https://php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php

Comment: lampa спасибо, попробую. Отпишусь...